# Convert SQL query to Yii Criteria Query

Tags: php, yii

SELECT a.*, c.category_name FROM products a JOIN product_categories b ON a.id = b.product_id
JOIN categories c ON b.category_id = c.id WHERE a.store_id = 20

Comment: This is not code converting service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$data = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('Your query here')->queryAll();
var_dump($data);
```